# loginwindow high CPU usage

Tags: applescript, performance, cpu

I have simple `zsh` script which executes the following code at a regular interval.

```
spotify_track=`osascript -e 'tell application "Spotify" to name of current track as string'`;
```

This is causes `loginwindow` process to consume high cpu (around 9-10%). Is `osascript` and `loginwindow` process related?

Comment: Are you interested in tracing the osascript to see what goes on?  And how are you invoking zsh, as a logon shell?  That would perhaps have something to do with it...

Comment: @FrancisfromResponseBase yup. any idea around how can I debug? also I'm using about script to display spotify track on zsh prompt. prompt is updated every 2 seconds using zsh `TRAPALRM` and `zle reset-prompt` feature